# Serve Angular app with pre-loaded server data

Tags: javascript, angular, asp.net-mvc

I am loading an Angular app in a .NET MVC .cshtml file.

The Angular app is all compiled by the webpack compiler (so it's static content at runtime) and the .cshtml only loads the app.js and an Angular component.

Now the first thing the app does when it loads on the client is go async to the server to get some data (in this case only a small call to get a total count of items).

And that annoys me, because when the page was loaded from the server, that same data was already present, in cache, on that server. So the server gives all JS and HTML to the client, *without* that 'itemcount' the server already has, and then the client has to go back to the server to get that data.

So what I would like to do is let the server give all the JS and HTML, *AND* that 'itemcount'. But I do not know how.

I can't inject it in the JS, because that is static. I could inject it into the HTML in a script tag, but the Angular app can't read it then.

So the only thing I could come up with is to generate, on the server, a JS file with the itemcount, and then load that JS file with a script tag, and then the App could also read it because it's a kind of global variable (which design time the Angular app doesn't know, so that kind of doesn't look nice).

Is there a better/nicer approach?

Comment: adding js will still need a server call to load that js file.what if you store count to local storage and fetch?

Comment: Sorry for the late reply. So then where do I put the code to store it in local storage? In the html in a script tag?

Comment: Yes you can do it inside some script tag in head section

Comment: Ok, thanks, will try that.